# F# deedle Frame, how to get row index and column index, and datatype for each column

Tags: f#, deedle

I have a few basic question regarding `Frame`, which seems not being address in the documentation.

1. How can I get the column headers?
2. How can I get the index (both column and row)?
3. How do I know the current datatype for each column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think most of it is in the documentation but a quick scan through the methods in VS will give you the following:

```
df.ColumnKeys
df.ColumnTypes
df.RowIndex
df.ColumnIndex
```